# Shpescape.com to Google Fusion Tables - not all rows were imported

Tags: google-fusion-tables, shapefile

I uploaded a shapefile with about 65,000 records (under the 100k row limit for Fusion Tables) into shpescape.com, which created this Fusion Table:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=3371869

Just under 40,000 rows were imported.

Quota issue? I've seen that there is a 250MB limit for tables, but I am not sure how I'll know when I've reached it. (Also, I am working with a nonprofit's Google Apps account; my settings show I am using 334MB of my 1024MB Docs quota overall, but it doesn't show tables alone.)

I could use ideas on what is preventing all my rows from uploading into the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible this shapefile contains a lot of complex polygons.

In this case, those that need simplification (due to their KML stringification being over the 1M character cell limit of Fusion Tables) are simplified individually.  Do this a bunch of times, and the process runs out of memory.

This is a bug and I should fix it; I'll try take the time to do that late next week.  Meanwhile I would suggest:

- Try presimplifying your geometries if you have access to software
  that lets you do that (such as QGIS)
- Share the location of the source
  shapefile (if its public) and I can test the above theory

Comment: I simplified the geometries; that helped.

Comment: @jlivni Thanks a lot for creating shpescape.com. Unfortunately, your website doesn't currently work. Do you have any other suggestions for converting shp files to fusion?